# XML file creation using XElement from Class Properties

Tags: c#, xml, lambda

I got a `List<Foo> fooList` of the class Foo which has several properties

```
Property01
Property02
Property03
```

I want to create an XML like

```
<Foos>
 <Foo>
  <Property01>value1</Property01>
  <Property02<value2</Property02>
  <Property03<value3</Property03>
 </Foo>
 <Foo>
  <Property01>value1</Property01>
  <Property02<value2</Property02>
  <Property03<value3</Property03>
 </Foo>
</Foos>
```

I tried

```
new XElement
("Foos",
 fooList.Select
  (Foo =>
   new XElement
   ("Foo",
      new XElement("Property01",Foo.Property01),
      new XElement("Property02",Foo.Property02),
      new XElement("Property03",Foo.Property03),
   )
  )
)
```

But the Lambda expression works only for one Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates the expected XML.
Maybe the problem is the last comma?

```
new XElement
("Foos",
 fooList.Select
  (Foo =>
   new XElement
   ("Foo",
      new XElement("Property01",Foo.Property01),
      new XElement("Property02",Foo.Property02),
      new XElement("Property03",Foo.Property03) // deleted comma
   )
  )
)
```